# Does there exist a field $K$ such that $\mathbb R \subsetneq K \subsetneq \mathbb C$?

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory, real-numbers

I'm thinking of unions of $\mathbb R$ with some subset of $\mathbb C$ but am not sure how to approach this without ending up with all of $\mathbb C$. Doe anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: In fact, you can prove something way stronger. If $K$ is a field, and $K\subseteq $ is a field extension of prime order, then there are no intermediate fields. The proof is using the tower lemma, very close to the proof of this one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No: the dimension of $\mathbb{C}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ is $2$.

If $K$ is an extension field of $F$, denote by $[K:F]$ the dimension of $K$ as a vector space over $F$. Then, if $F_1\subseteq F_2\subseteq F_3$ are fields, we have
$$
[F_3:F_1]=[F_3:F_2][F_2:F_1]
$$
(assuming $[F_3:F_1]$ is finite then also $[F_3:F_2]$ and $[F_2:F_1]$ is finite and conversely).

---

Of course there's an elementary proof. Suppose $a+bi\in K$, $a+bi\notin\mathbb{R}$. Then $b\ne0$, so
$$
i=((a+bi)-a)b^{-1}\in K
$$
and therefore $K=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @tomasz It depends on what you consider elementary; the second proof just uses the fact that a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $\mathbb{R}$ and $i$ is $\mathbb{C}$, which is obvious. So the second proof is *surely* elementary.

Comment: not any less obvious that that there's no vector space intermediate between a $1$-dimensional and a $2$-dimensional one. But I see now that you've used slightly different argument using tower lemma, so yeah, that's less elementary.

Answer (score 4):

Any intermediate field between $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ is in particular an $\Bbb R$-vector subspace of $\Bbb C$. Since $\dim_{\Bbb R}\Bbb C=2$, it is either equal to $\Bbb R$ or to $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 3):

and just very simply if $z \in \mathbb{K} \subset \mathbb{C}$ but $z \notin \mathbb{R}$ then it must be of the form $a + ib$ with $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \ne 0$. hence $i \in \mathbb{K}$ so $\mathbb{C} \subset \mathbb{R}(i) \subset \mathbb{K}$

Answer (score 2):

No, since if $\mathbb R\subset K$, then $K$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$ and in the same way $K\subset\mathbb C$ means that $\mathbb C$ is a vector space over $K$. Finally $\mathbb C$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$ of dimension 2, and $K$ is a subspace. Therefore $K$ has dimension either 1 or 2. In the first case it is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$ and contains $\mathbb R$, so it is $\mathbb R$ and in the second - all of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: A completely elementary proof would be to assume that K has an element with a nonzero imaginary part and show that in this case K contains $i$ and therefore contains all of $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Look at the tower lemma. Otherwise $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{R}]=[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{K}][\mathbb{K}:\mathbb{R}]>2$ which is a contradiction . By the way, take a look at the Artin Schreier theorem. It is magnificent.

Comment: How is the Artin-Schreier theorem related to this?

Comment: It talks about finite extensions between fields and its algebraic closures. Regardless of the fact that it does not directly relate to this, it is close enough and beautiful enough (In my opinion) for the OP to see.

Answer (score 0):

suppose a field $K\subseteq \mathbb C $ contains $\mathbb R$ properly. Then it contains a non-real element $x+iy$, consequently it contains all elements of the form $z+iy$ with $z\in \mathbb R$.

We conclude it contains $z^2-y^2 + 2zyi$ for all $z\in \mathbb R$. And therefore it contains $2zyi$ for all $z\in \mathbb R$.

We conclude it contains $zi$ for every $z\in \mathbb R$, this shows $K=\mathbb C$.